# Geometric Distribution in R

Tags: r, self-study, geometric-distribution

I'm trying to solve a problem involving a Geometric Distribution with $p = 0.20$ and $x = 5$. I use the formula and R, but I get two different answers:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X = x) & = & p(1 - p)^{x - 1} \\
P(X = 5) & = & (0.20)(1 - 0.20)^{5 - 1} \\
& = & (0.20)(0.80)^4 \\
& = & 0.08192
\end{eqnarray*}

$${\tt dgeom(x, p) = dgeom(5, 0.2) = 0.065536}$$

Can anyone explain why this would be the case?

Comment: Which pmf formula is `dgeom` using? (Hint: view the help via `?dgeom`.)

Comment: Very interesting. It is using $P(X = x) = p(1 - p)^x$. Is there a reason for this? Is there a function using the PMF I used in my by-hand calculations?

Comment: The reason is that there are 2 parameterizations for the geometric distribution in wide usage (for instance, on Wikipedia). I'm not aware of a function that does what you request, but the easiest solution would be to write your own function that just calls `dgeom` using the appropriate arguments.

Comment: This is a problem with *all* statistical software.  You, the user, *must* consult the documentation and--if you care at all about using the software correctly--you *must* test it against independent calculations.  The issue is that no distribution has a unique or universal parameterization.  That is what @Sycorax hints at in the first comment.  Indeed, the help page for `dgeom` states the density it computes is $$p(x)=p\,(1-p)^x,$$ whereas in your question you have assumed the exponent is $x-1.$ The solution is clear.

Comment: One version counts the trials until the first Success is seen. The other counts the Failures encountered before the first Success. // In R, code `dgeom(4, .2)` returns
$0.08192.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) gives two different distributions

- The probability distribution of the number $X$ of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$;
- The probability distribution of the number $Y=X-1$ of failures before the first success, supported on the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$.

and R uses the second of these while you are using the first. This should be clear from the [documentation using `?dgeom`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Geometric.html).

> The geometric distribution with `prob = p` has density
>
> `p(x) = p (1-p)^x`
>
> for `x = 0, 1, 2, …, 0 < p ≤ 1`.

I have actually seen two other distributions called geometric, essentially where success and failure are swapped round.

You can easily create functions which match your desired distribution, for example with

```
dgeom1 <- function(x, ...){ dgeom(x - 1, ...) }
pgeom1 <- function(q, ...){ pgeom(q - 1, ...) }
qgeom1 <- function(p, ...){ qgeom(p, ...) + 1 }
rgeom1 <- function(n, ...){ rgeom(n, ...) + 1 }
```

and then for example you get

```
dgeom1(5,0.2)
# 0.08192
```