Is there any question as to what the likelihood function for a geometric distribution is?
Because I've read it is either

$g(x) = 
\prod_{i=1}^∞\ p(1-p)^{x_i}$

or

$g(x) = 
\prod_{i=1}^∞\ p(1-p)^{x_i-1}$

So I'm really confused.
Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429910/mle-of-the-geometric-distribution
Edit: My iid observations go from $x_1, x_2$ etc ...

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.

Hint:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560497/geometric-distribution-in-r

Distributions don't have likelihood functions.  Are you perhaps referring to the probability function?

There are two different versions of the geometric in common use. The number of trials version and the number of failures version. Which do you need?

The geometric distribution is counting the number of trials/failures in a series of Bernoulli trials untill a success occurs.
The difference between $x_i$ and $x_i-1$, is whether $x_i$ refers to the number of trials, or the number of failures (which differ by one).

Btw, likelihood functions are typically described as functions of the parameter: $g(p)$, instead of $g(x)$.
